# Data-Grid events firing on init and not after

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mui-datatable

Background: Hello, I am using React with the latest MUI version of Material-UI. I am using Data-Grid in a separate file in my components folder. I call the component from my App and use states to handle adding rows. On init 50 rows are added.

Issue: When I add `onRowEditStart={console.log("Start")}` & `onRowEditStop={console.log("stop")}` to the DataGrid component, they are only fired on page load, but if I edit a column after, no events are fired?

Whole components/DataGrid.js added.

If anyone has info on this would be great, thanks!

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { DataGrid, GridToolbar } from '@mui/x-data-grid';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import Stack from '@mui/material/Stack';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';

export default function Table(props) {

const [rows, setRows] = React.useState(props.rows);

React.useEffect(() => {
    setRows(props.rows);
  }, [props.rows]);

  return (
    <div style={{ width: '100%' }}>
      <Stack
        sx={{ width: '100%', mb: 1 }}
        direction="row"
        alignItems="flex-start"
        columnGap={1}
      >
      </Stack>
      <Box sx={{ height: 400, bgcolor: 'background.paper' }}>
        <DataGrid autoHeight 
        components={{
            Toolbar: GridToolbar,
        }}
        pageSize={25}
        rowsPerPageOptions={[25, 50, 100]}
        onRowEditStart={console.log("Start")}
        onRowEditStop={console.log("stop")}
        experimentalFeatures={{ newEditingApi: true }}
        rows={rows} 
        columns={props.columns} 
        loading={props.rows.length === 0}
        columnGap={1}
        rowHeight={75}
        />
      </Box>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason for this is because both `onRowEditStart` and `onRowEditStop` accept *functions*.

If you replace your code with the following, it will work.

```
onRowEditStart={() => console.log("Start")}
onRowEditStop={() => console.log("stop")}
```

Notice the difference in your code.

```
onRowEditStart={console.log("Start")} // evaluated on page load
onRowEditStop={console.log("stop")} // evaluated on page load
```

By passing a function (`onRowEditStart={() => console.log("Start")}`), the `console.log("Start")` will only be run when a row edit has started.

Comment: Thanks for the help btw.

I tried what you suggested, and now the event is never fired? You had a bug with the `)` but even that fixed did nit fire anything. Could it be because the rows and columns are declared in a diff file and passed in as props?

Comment: Interesting. I haven't used Material UI before, but I [created a sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/disablestopeditmodeonfocusout-material-demo-forked-d2t2b0?file=/demo.tsx) and noticed that `onCellEditStart` does fire when editing a cell, but `onRowEditStart` does not and I'm not sure why (I'm not sure what it means to edit a row, but it seems that editing a cell doesn't also cause the `onRowEditStart` event to fire).